# Javascript: Reading data type from a string of the data type name, from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, types

I have a program that behaves differently depending on what the datatype of an attribute is. Within this program I can set the data type by doing something like

```
const myObject = new MyObject ();
myObject.numberType = number
myObject.main()
```

I want to be able to read the data type from a json file, but I cannot record the data types literally within the json, the best I can do is record a string containing text that matches the data type

For example

```json
{
    "type1": "number",
    "type2": "string"
}
```

I would like to change my program to look more like the program below and have it behave the same

```js
import types from './types.json' assert { type: "json" };
// const types = require ('./types.json'); // if using es5

const myObject = new MyObject ();
myObject.numberType = types['type1'];  // This line will need some changing
myObject.main()
```

---

## MRE

### json

```json
{
    "type1": "number",
    "type2": "string"
}
```

### js

```js
import types from './types.json' assert { type: "json" };

async function main () {

    const type1 = typeof (types['type1']);
    const type2 = typeof (types['type2']);

    console.log (type1);
    console.log (type2);

};

main ();
```

### current output

```
string
string
```

### desired output

```
number
string
```

I need to save the actual types in the variables though, not strings whose text matches the type

---

I'm basically trying to record my data types within a json file and have my program read it somehow

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254787/discussion-on-question-by-sam-javascript-reading-data-type-from-a-string-of-the); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
const type1 = types['type1'];
const type2 = types["type2"];
```

Comment: You might as well have written `const getType = type => type;`. How does this help?

Comment: @astro62 I think what you had before was the solution actually, I literally need the types, not strings whose text matches the types

Comment: @Sam You keep saying that, but types are not runtime values in JS. They're just concepts in the specification, not actual data.

Comment: @Unmitigated This produces the desired output that the OP asked for.

Comment: @Barmar I was pointing out that the whole `getType` function was redundant. There definitely seems to be some misunderstandings here though.

Comment: @Unmitigated I didn't see the answer and your comment until it was edited to remove the getType function, so I didn't understand the context.